# SSIS ForEach ADO Enumerator - Performance Issues

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, business-intelligence

This is a best practice/other approach question about using a ADO Enumerator ForEach loop.

My data is financial accounts, coming from a source system into a data warehouse.
The current structure of the data is a list of financial transactions eg.

```
+-----------------------+----------+-----------+------------+------+
|      AccountGUID      | Increase | Decrease  |    Date    | Tags |
+-----------------------+----------+-----------+------------+------+
| 00000-0000-0000-00000 |        0 |    100.00 | 01-01-2018 | Val1 |
| 00000-0000-0000-00000 |   200.00 |         0 | 03-01-2018 | Val3 |
| 00000-0000-0000-00000 |   400.00 |         0 | 06-01-2018 | Val1 |
| 00000-0000-0000-00000 |        0 |    170.00 | 08-01-2018 | Val1 |
| 00000-0000-0000-00002 |   200.00 |         0 | 04-01-2018 | Val1 |
| 00000-0000-0000-00002 |        0 |    100.00 | 09-01-2018 | Val1 |
+-----------------------+----------+-----------+------------+------+
```

My SSIS Package, current has two forEach Loops

1. All Time Balances
2. End Of Month Balances

**All Time Balances**

Passes AccountGUID into the loop and selects all transactions for that account. It then orders them by date with the first transaction being first and assigns it a sequence number.

Once the sequence number is assigned, it begins to count the current balances based on the increase and decrease cols, along with the tag col to work out which balance its dealing with.

It finishes this off by assigning the latest record with a Current flag.

**All Time Balances - Work Flow**

```
->Get All Account ID's in Staging table
|-> Write all Account GUID's to object variable
|--> ADO Enumerator ForEach - Loop Account GUID List - Write GUID to variable
|---> (Data Flow) Select all transactions for Account GUID
|----> (Data Flow) Order all transactions by date and assign Sequence number
|-----> (Data Flow) Run each row through a script component transformation to calculate running totals for each record
|------> (Data Flow) Insert balance data into staging table
```

**End Of Month Balances**

The second package, End of Month does something very similar with the exception of a second loop. The select will find the earliest transnational record and the latest transnational record. Using those two dates it will figure out all the months between those two and loop for each of those months.

Inside the date loop, it does pretty much the same thing, works out the balances based on tags and stamps the end of month record for each account.

**The Issue/Question**

All of this currently works fine, but the performance is horrible.

In one database with approx 8000 Accounts and 500,000 transactions. This process takes upwards of a day to run. This being one of our smaller clients, I tremble at the idea of running it for our heavy databases.

Is there a better approach to doing this, using SQL cursors or so other neat way I have not seen?

Comment: I might be missing something. Is there a reason you're not using SQL with SUM and GROUP BY for your inserts? I don't get why you're using so many discrete steps.

Comment: Hey Ben, So the reason its currently doing is that way is for point in time. So taking the table at the top. For account 00000-0000-0000-00000, on 01-01 the balance is -100 and on 03-01 the balance is +100, 06-01 balance +500. Other than doing running balances, how would you see that working using SUM and Group by to keep that running value without complex WHERE clauses?

Comment: Oh ok. The way I read it was that you wanted a total sum and a sum per month, not incremental. Fair enough.

Comment: Try using a Execute Sql Statement instead of doing it  in a dataflow. Ordering data in dataflows can be very slow.

Comment: Are you saying just do the sort and sequence in a execute sql task? I feel like the sheer number of loops is effecting it pretty badly - in debug the sort doesn't appear to have a huge impact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I have managed to take my package execution from around 3 days to about 11 minutes all up.

I ran a profiler and standard windows stats while running the loops and found a few interesting things.

Firstly, there was almost no utilization of HDD, CPU, RAM or network during the execution of the packages. It told me what I kind of already knew, that it was not running as quickly as it could.

What I did notice, between each execution of the loop there was a 1 to 2ms delay before the next instance of the loop started executing.

Eventually I found that every time a new instance of the loop began, SSIS created a new connection to the SQL database, it appears that this is SSIS's default behavior. Whenever you create a Source or Destination, you are adding a connection delay to your project.

**The Fix:**

Now this was an odd fix, you need to go into your connection manager (The odd bit) it must be the onscreen window not in the right hand project manager window.

If you select your connect that is referenced in the loop, the properties window on the right side (In my layout anyway) you will see the option called "RetainSameConnection" which be default is set to false.

By setting this to true, I eliminated the 2ms delay.

**Considerations:**

In doing this I created a heap of other issues, which really just highlighted areas of my package that I had not thought out well.

Some things that appears to be impacted by this change were stored procedures that used temp tables, these seemed to break instantly. I assume that is because of how SQL handles temp tables, in closing the connection and reopening, you can be pretty certain that the temp table is gone. With the same connection setting, the chance of running into temp tables appears to be an issue again.

I removed all temp tables and replaced them with CTE statements, this appears to fix this issue.

The second major issue I found was with tasks that ran parallel and both used the same connection manager. From this I received an error that SQL is still trying to run the previous statement. This bombed out my package.

To get around this, I created a duplicate connection manager (All up I made three connection managers for the same database).

Once I had my connections set up, I went into each of my parallel Source and Destinations and assigned them their own connection manager. This appears to have resolved the last error I received.

**Conclusion:**

They may be more unforeseen issues in doing this, but for now my packages are lightening quick and this highlighted some faults in my design.